# Can I run Snort on a slow computer?

Tags: ids, snort

I'm trying to use a device with 1GB of RAM and a Single 800 MHz core CPU.
I will use Snort to analyze traffic on my LAN network. Snort, unfortunately, cannot analyze all the traffic (sometimes it triggers an alert after a trigger, sometimes not).

- Is there a way to say "Analyze X Mbps of traffic", otherwise let the traffic flow?
- Can you tell me where I can get a list of "reduced" RuleSet with only the most *terrible* attacks? *Right now I just use the CRITICAL ruleset*
- Can FWSNORT be a good alternative?

Comment: if you go with #1, you might as well not run snort at all - better late than never?

Comment: "critical" = "terrible"

Comment: FWSNORT is a completely different product - we can't tell you if it is an alternative unless you state what your requirements are (and then you can likely answer that for yourself)

Comment: 100% agree with the above comments. I would also suggest you either get a higher spec machine, or ditch SNORT. It's going to cause you more hassle trying to get it to work than the 'protection' you are aiming for.

Comment: No, I wouldn't run snort on that machine. Snort is fairly heavy and needs some decent resources. I've even had trouble running it with 2GB of RAM and 2 CPU cores on a Digital Ocean box. It would take up a majority of my resources.

Comment: Did you custom build your OS  before running snort on such machine spec? i will shutdown as many services as possible.

Comment: Above all thanks to all for your answers.
@shroeder: It's not my choice. I'd like to have different levels of service, based on hardware. Snort is not the only software running, so I need to cap it basing my limits on the hardware.
I know FwSnort uses another approach, but It's even true that IPtables moves the effort to the kernel space; I think I have saturation of queues for kernel/user space communication

Comment: @mootmoot: It's just Ubuntu on a custom kernel, yep.

Answer (score 1):

It all depends on how much traffic you're attempting to monitor, but the most important factor of all your actual configuration.

There is a few actions you can do to enhance performance of your setup

- Limit the scope of traffic to be monitored.
- Optimize your Snort/Suricata configuration. Suricata will probably not give you much extras since it's multi-threaded and you only have one CPU core.
- As you mentioned yourself, amount of rules implemented in your sensor have a strong performance impact. I'm not aware of any limited ruleset, but you can disable unnecessary rules yourself. There's plenty of different ruleset manager such as [Polman](https://github.com/gamelinux/polman), [PulledPork](https://github.com/shirkdog/pulledpork). These are fairly old, and there might be more useful software/helpers for these tasks available.
- OS level optimizations

I agree with above comments, that you want more RAM, CPU cores, strong NICs (at least two), and potentially even GPUs to get the most of your sensor setup.